# Calling the 'stop' function that stops the clock by clicking <li> </ li>. Passing functions 'stop' between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Expected effect:

1. Click Name A. Name A is active
2. When I click on the 'Name B' element, I want to call the 'stopTimer ()' function. Stop the time in the element 'Name A' and run function 'stopTimer()'

When I click an element such as 'Name A', name A is active, I can not call the 'stopTimer ()' function until I click 'Name B'

And vice versa when item 'Name B' is active. Click item 'Name A' call function 'stopTimer ()'

Is this solution possible at all? I am asking for advice.

**Updated:**

All code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kxuvgn

I understood my mistake. I should put the function `stopTimer ()` in the parent `App`. The function `stopTimer` is needed both in the`App`, when I click

to stop the clock, as well as in the `Stopwatch` component plugged into the`stop` button. Where should I set this: `{timerOn: false}); clearInterval (this.timer);`That it was common for both components?

```
stopTimer = () => {
     this.setState ({timerOn: false});
     clearInterval (this.timer);
};
```

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      selectedTodoId: '',
      selectedTabId: null,
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'A',
          description: 'Hello'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'B',
          description: 'World'
        }
      ],
      selectIndex: null
    };
  }

  stopTimer = (timer, timerOn) => {
    this.setState({ timerOn: timerOn });
    clearInterval(timer);
  };

   select = (id) => {
     if(id !== this.state.selectedTabId){
      this.setState({
        selectedTodoId: id,
        selectedTabId: id
      })
      this.stopTimer();
    }
  }

  isActive = (id) => {
    return this.state.selectedTabId === id;
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.items
              .map((item, index) =>
                <Item
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  item={item}
                  select={this.select}
                  items = {this.state.items}
                  selectIndex = {this.state.selectIndex}
                  isActive= {this.isActive(item.id)}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
         <ItemDetails
            items = {this.state.items}
            selectIndex = {this.state.selectIndex}
            resul={this.state.resul}
          />
          <Stopwatch
            stopTimer = {this.stopTimer}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Watch**

```
class Stopwatch extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    };
  }

  startTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerOn: true,
      timerTime: this.state.timerTime,
      timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.timerTime
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        timerTime: Date.now() - this.state.timerStart
      });
    }, 10);
  };

  stopTimer = () => {
    this.setState({ timerOn: false });
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };

  resetTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    });
  };

  render() {
      const { timerTime } = this.state;
      let centiseconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 10) % 100)).slice(-2);
      let seconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2);
      let minutes = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2);
      let hours = ("0" + Math.floor(timerTime / 3600000)).slice(-2);

    return (
      <div>


    <div className="Stopwatch-display">
      {hours} : {minutes} : {seconds} 
    </div>


    { (
    <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
    )}

    {(
      <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>
    )}

    {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime > 0 && (
      <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>Reset</button>
    )}
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is easily possible. You just need to change where you're putting what in your components. If you want functions/state to be shared between components, you have to lift it up to a common parent component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to lift your state up for this, before the child unmounts, pass the value to
parent component to store.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.stopTimer();
  this.props.updateTimerTime(this.props.index, this.state.timerTime);
}
```

When the child component mounts set the state from props passed from parent component.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    timerTime: this.props.timerTime,
  });
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v67jjc)